# Classic ASP on IIS7: refusing to send errors to browser on 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have classic ASP running on IIS 7.

Even though I configured the ASP "Debugging Properties" to "Send Errors to Browser = True", the web app REFUSES to send errors to the browser and continues to send a 500 internal server error.

- My browser has "Show Friendly HTTP Error Messages" unchecked.
- Failed Request Tracing is installed (not sure if that's related)
- Happens both on web pages loaded locally on the server and remotely
- The App Pool is integrated (not sure if that matters)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Try :
Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager **—>** Default Web Site **—>** Click Error Pages properties and select Detail errors

Comment: I also had to convert  my virtual directory into an Application

Answer (score 9):

I was having the same issue with a Classic ASP app running in a subfolder of a site. I had enabled detailed errors and the 500 was still showing. My resolution was to enable parent paths in the ASP section in IIS for the site as the application was referencing the parent folder using "../":

[image: CEnable Parent Paths for Classic ASP - IIS]

Comment: I always forget about this one. Many years pass between having to spin up a new classic ASP site and then BAM! Weird 500 errors. This is usually the problem.

Answer (score 8):

I had this occuring on a Classic ASP application running in a **subfolder** of a site. The solution was:

`IIS > Click into your Site > Click into your Application folder > Error Pages > Edit Feature Settings > set to: Detailed Errors`

Answer (score 8):

IIS Manager >> double click the **ASP** icon to open the ASP page. Expand the Debugging Properties node and set Send Errors To Browser to **True**.

[image]

[image]

Refer : http://www.chestysoft.com/asp-error-messages.asp

Answer (score 3):

If your website is configured to connect to the physical path of the website as a specific user, instaed of using pass-through authentication, you may get this error if there is a permissions error with this user. It may also be necessary to restart the Windows Process Activation Service and then restart IIS.

Comment: This was the approximate case for me: a 500 error with nothing to show for it in any log file.  But the IIS process couldn't open the physical path (it was in my home dir, and IIS was using pass-through auth).

Comment: That was it.  We have an Web service that was returning error 500.  The permission was removed to application folder.  Once I granted read permission to "everyone" it started working.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are hosting the project in a shared environment then you can use the following snippet to view the errors.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
```

Refer this URL for complete information http://blogs.iis.net/rickbarber/working-past-500-internal-server-error

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 1):

I had a 500 error with an ASP Classic application I had just installed on a new server (Windows 2019). Every URL on the application returned 500, no matter what. But no errors were being shown in the Windows event log, and despite configuring detailed errors, as mentioned in several the other answers here, no specific error was being displayed in the browser.

The only clue was in the IIS logs, which showed the HTTP status code as 500, and the IIS **substatus** code as 19. So a 500.19 error.

That led me to
and the specific issue I was having was answered by the second part of this section:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-error-500-19-webpage#hresult-code-0x80070005

which says:

> Don't configure the website to use UNC pass-through authentication to
> access the remote UNC share. Instead, specify a user account that has
> the appropriate permissions to access the remote UNC share.

and (this is the part I needed to do):

> Grant the Read permission to the IIS_IUSRS group for the
> ApplicationHost.config or Web.config file. To do it, follow these
> steps:
>
> In Windows Explorer, locate the folder that contains the
> ApplicationHost.config file that is associated with the website, or
> locate the virtual directories or the application directories that
> contain the Web.config file that is associated with the website.
>
> Note
>
> The Web.config file may not be in the virtual directories or the
> application directories in IIS. Even in this situation, you have to
> follow these steps.
>
> Right-click the folder that contains the ApplicationHost.config file,
> or right-click the virtual or application directories that may contain
> the Web.config file.
>
> Select Properties.
>
> Select the Security tab, and then Select Edit.
>
> Select Add.
>
> In the Enter the object names to select box, type
> \IIS_IUSRS, select Check Names, and then select OK.
>
> Note
>
> is a placeholder for the computer name.
>
> Select the Read check box, and then select OK.
>
> In the Properties dialog box for the folder, select OK.
>
> Note
>
> Make sure that the folder properties are inherited by the
> ApplicationHost.config and Web.config files so that IIS_IUSRS has the
> Read permission for those files.