# Decoding error 500 on IIS7

Tags: error-handling, iis-7

I am getting error 500, looking at the log I can see the http headers with the error 500, but how do I find out why it's happening? Is there any other tool I should be looking at? The event viewer is also not showing anything.

Thanks

Comment: Is it an aspx page?  Have you tried turning off custom errors in your web.config to see if you get a better error message?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453791/classic-asp-on-iis7-refusing-to-send-errors-to-browser-on-500-internal-server-e

Answer (score 12):

As was also answered to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453791/classic-asp-on-iis7-refusing-to-send-errors-to-browser-on-500-internal-server-e), a good way to get more detailed information on error 500 is to enable detailed error reporting:

Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager —> Your Web Site —> Error Pages -> Edit Feature Settings -> select "Detailed errors"