# ASP will not run unless logged into console

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

I am moving an existing ASP application from IIS5 on Win2003 to IIS7 on Win2008.

After going over all the install notes and setting up ASP to run, everything worked fine while I was logged into the console.

As soon as I log off the console, no ASP application will run. I get a 500 error even though normal .htm pages will render from the site fine.

I tried a simple page with only a `response.write " Hell "` and it fails with a 500 error. I set up Failed Request error logging and it just says 500 error as soon as it calls the ASP script.

How can this be solved?

**Solution**

Tweaked a setting in IIS:

- Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager ->
- Default Web Site ->
- Error Pages properties
- select Detail errors
- Reset to Detailed errors only and now everything works

Comment: Just to confirm, classic ASP?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the blue Google Search:

[Classic ASP on IIS7: refusing to send errors to browser on 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453791/classic-asp-on-iis7-refusing-to-send-errors-to-browser-on-500-internal-server-er)

Does this help you ?

Comment: Thanks, but that does not seem to make any difference

Comment: Just went back to double check and found setting was Detailed errors for local requests and customer eero for remote---