# Classic ASP application on IIS7 throwing 500 error

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Classic ASP on IIS7: refusing to send errors to browser on 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453791/classic-asp-on-iis7-refusing-to-send-errors-to-browser-on-500-internal-server-er)

I have done the following (as suggested in other posts) and still get the 500 error:

1. Set Send Errors To Brower = true in *ASP* properties in IIS
2. Unchecked show friendly errors in browser
3. Set *Error Pages* properties to show Detailed Error in IIS

ASP handler does seem to be mapped correctly.

The application pool has been set to *Classic* mode.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you using an Access database?

Comment: Is the application pool using Classic Pipeline mode?

Comment: Yes app pool is set to use Classic mode

Comment: Any description in error page?

Comment: can you show any more detailed error information - without giving connection string details, etc away?

Comment: I do wish there was a detailed error! Issue is I'm unable to view it as it simply throws the 500 error.

Comment: Check the IIS logs. Maybe you'll find more detailed information. If the  `web.config` is exists in the root try to rename it to disable. Sometimes, if there are entries of the modules are not installed yet in the configuration, may be occurs this kinds of senseless errors. And if necessary [enable 32-Bit applications](http://help.webcontrolcenter.com/KB/a1114/how-to-enable-a-32-bit-application-pool-in-iis7-dedicatedvps.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally sorted this out with the help of my sys admin!

The classic asp application was in a sub-folder. To get it working, the classic asp application's app pool had to be given access to the main folder and not just the sub-folder as it was using assets from the main folder.

Thanks heaps to all those who tried to help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[From the IIS blog...](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2007/05/21/tips-for-classic-asp-developers-on-iis7.aspx)

> Script errors no longer shown in browser by default
>
> As a result of our security paranoia, we turned off ASP's default behavior of sending script errors (including line number and code snippet to the browser.
>
> ...
>
> To revert back to IIS6- behavior, simply run the following command:
>
> ```
> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:asp -scriptErrorSentToBrowser:true
> ```

Hopefully that will at least get you to the line that's throwing the error...

Comment: Sorry, that didn't seem to work either. Still have same issue.

Comment: Bummer.  How about this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453791/classic-asp-on-iis7-refusing-to-send-errors-to-browser-on-500-internal-server-er/1455041#1455041

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your running your AppPool under "Integrated" pipeline mode, change this to "Classic"  and you should be right.

see this blog [Running classic ASP on IIS 7](http://www.alexthissen.nl/blogs/main/archive/2008/02/18/running-classic-asp-on-iis-7.aspx)

Comment: AppPool is running on classic mode only.