# Classic ASP gives Internal Server Error 500

Tags: asp-classic, internal-server-error

Need your help with an legacy ASP application hoisted on IIS 7. The application connects to oracle 10 and fetches data. If the rows exceed 500 then Internal Server 500 error is shown in the browser.  How to overcome this ? Is there any logs I can check to fine out this error.  Is there anything i need to do on timeout parameters.

Any pointers will be of great help.

Thanks a zillion.

Comment: Check this post for getting additional error information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453791/classic-asp-on-iis7-refusing-to-send-errors-to-browser-on-500-internal-server-e

Comment: Also disable IE friendly error messages.

Comment: If you are running IIS7 and want decent error messages, as well as disabling Friendly HTTP Error Messages, you need to go into IIS Manager, go to your website, in the ASP section go to: Compilation > Debugging Properties > Send Errors to Browser = True. This should make them a little more helpful:)

Comment: Also > Default Web Site —> Click Error Pages properties and select Detail errors

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried the methods above to see what kind of error you are getting and it is buffer related, then you need to increase the response buffer limit. in IIS 7, click on the website, click on ASP, click on limits properties, increase the response buffer limit and script time-out limit as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: Or, you can also add `response.flush` something in your code, like every 100 records.  So, results are sent to the client before the entire page is generated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I wanted to share my issue with others in hopes that it might also help.

In my case, I had set the **Response Buffer Limit** of one of the websites to a higher number, leaving the rest of the websites to the default 0 (Zero), which caused all the sites to go down. I was unaware the other websites were down until today. They had been down for five days.

To set the **Response Buffer Limit**
Open **IIS**
Select the **Server Instance**
In the Right Panel under **IIS**, choose **ASP**
Under **Limits Properties**
**Response Buffer Limit** = change 0 to 4194304
(Or, leave all websites as 0)