# IIS 7 error 500 internal server error in asp

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

I am having a asp web application running through IIS...If i insert data in a form from my system..The application connects to SQL Server 2008 and insert data.. i am able to insert...if i do the same process through my network systems ..i am getting error as "**500 - internal server error. there is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed**"..How to overcome this ?

Answer (score 1):

First check you could connect to SQl2008 successfully with the credentials you gave in your asp application. 
Then check if the user has got permissions to insert data into the database.

This error usually comes up when either of the above cases is true.
good luck

Answer (score 1):

First, you will have to activate Detailed Server Errors (see [Classic ASP on IIS7: refusing to send errors to browser on 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453791/classic-asp-on-iis7-refusing-to-send-errors-to-browser-on-500-internal-server-e?rq=1) for instance), to see what causes the error.

It *may* be a DB error, but it could also be a script syntax error or something else. Classic ASP is not compiled, so even simple syntax errors show up only when the code is executed.