# ASP forms can't be send anymore - 500 - Internal server error

Tags: html, asp.net, asp-classic, internal-server-error

The mail forms on the site of a company (www.hendrixhuybregts.nl) I work for are not working. When you enter the submit it goes to the 500 - internal server error page. I know by now from Google-ing that it is quite a random error message that doesn't really help.

The code of the pages concerned:

[ASP mail](http://www.filedropper.com/mail):

```vb
<%
response.write ""

controle_veld=0

check_invoer

if controle_veld=1 then
  response.write ""
else
  MyBody = "<HTML>" & vbcrlf & _
    "<BODY>" & vbcrlf & _
    "<TABLE>" & vbcrlf & _    
    "<TR><TD>Gegevens: </TD><TD>" & vbcrlf & _ 
    "<TR><TD>Naam: </TD><TD>" & Request.form("naam") & "</TD></TR>" & vbcrlf & _ 
    "<TR><TD>Telefoon: </TD><TD>" & Request.form("telefoon") & "</TD></TR>" & vbcrlf & _ 
    "<TR><TD>E-mail: </TD><TD>" & Request.form("email") & "</TD></TR>" & vbcrlf & _ 
    "<TR><TD>Vraag / Opmerking: </TD><TD>" & Request.form("opmerking") & "</TD></TR>" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & _ 

    "</body>"& _ 
    "</html>" 

  Const CdoBodyFormatHTML = 0
  Const CdoBodyFormatText = 1
  Const CdoMailFormatMime = 0
  Const CdoMailFormatText = 1

  Set myMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
  myMail.From     = "info@dh-p.nl"
  myMail.To       = "info@dh-p.nl"
  myMail.Subject  = "Contactformulier website"
  myMail.HTMLBody = MyBody
  myMail.Send
  set myMail = nothing

  response.redirect "bedankt.html"
end if
%>

<%
sub check_invoer
  response.write "<br>"
  if request.form("naam")="" then
    response.write "U heeft het veld <B>Naam</B> niet ingevuld.<br>"
    controle_veld=1
  end if
  if request.form("telefoon")="" then
    response.write "U heeft het veld <B>Telefoon</B> niet ingevuld.<br>"
    controle_veld=1
  end if
  if request.form("email")="" then
    response.write "U heeft het veld <B>E-mail</B> niet ingevuld.<br>"
    controle_veld=1
  end if
end sub
%>
```

[ASP mail 2](http://www.filedropper.com/mail2): (*Editor* - Not included source as it looks similar to the above).

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: What's random about a `500 Internal Server Error`?, it means that there is a problem with the page and ASP (whether it's [tag:asp.net] or [tag:asp-classic] which you confirm which??) can't process it. For more detailed information about the error make sure you have detailed errors enabled.

Comment: Please note that `Classic ASP` and `ASP.NET` are as different as `JavaScript` and `Java`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure from what you provided that anyone can help you fix it, but we can point you in the right direction.

First off,

> **[Quote](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25409170/692942) by [@yvette-d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3960939/yvette-d)**
>
> *" I know by now from Google-ing that it is quite a random error message that doesn't really help."*

is complete nonsense. The `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error` is your most useful resource, unfortunately by default detailed errors are switched off remotely.

To rectify this they need to be switched back on there are various answers on this very site to this particular issue and rather then me regurgitating what they have already answered I will point you to a few of them.

> Generated from a [quick search on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp-classic%5D+iis+500+error)
>
> - [Answer by @vaclav-elias to Detailed 500 error message, ASP + IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2765795/692942)
> - [Answer by @lsalamon to Classic ASP on IIS7: refusing to send errors to browser on 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1455041/692942)

Once you have identified the cause of the error (to the line number) maybe come back and update the question then we might be able to help further.

Comment: Thanks for the tips I'll try to find out more info!