# IIS 7.5: problem with Application pool

Tags: iis-7, application-pool

several time in day my Application pool is stopped with following error:

> Application pool 'MyApplicationPool'
>   is being automatically disabled due to
>   a series of failures in the
>   process(es) serving that application
>   pool.

How to resolve this?

thanks, for the any advice.

Comment: Do you have anything in the event log that might help elaborate the problem?

Comment: this error I've got from Windows logs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because your application pool is crashing more than 5 times in 5 minutes [default settings - Rapid Fail]

Instead of disabling Rapid Fail, you should consider taking Crash Dumps and try to find out the root cause. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rahulso/archive/2006/03/02/what-is-a-crash-technically-in-asp-net-and-what-to-do-if-it-happens.aspx

Comment: The IIS diagnostics toolkit that is referred to in the link you provided does not exist anymore. How to approach this issue on Windows 8 with IIS7.5? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and after some struggle I realized it was caused by a change in my domain password that runs the application pool. Going to the application pool > Advanced Settings > Process Model > Identity and set it with the new password.

Comment: Note: I this is a tiny bit different than what you said.

Going to the application pool > Advanced Settings > Process Model > Identity and set it to LocalSystem. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You may not have the same exception causing the application pool to recycle, but this answer should address your situation as well: [A process serving application pool 'Classic .NET AppPool' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. HTTP Error 503](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445566/a-process-serving-application-pool-classic-net-apppool-suffered-a-fatal-commun/2114736#2114736)

The gist of it is that something in your application is causing the app pool to keep recycling itself. You'll need to determine what is throwing so many exceptions. After you've fixed the cause of the exceptions, your app pool should run without recycling itself to the point where it hits the Rapid Fail Protection limit.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and after a few hours of wrestling with it and following solutions that didnt work, I went to Application Pool > Advanced Settings > Process Model > Identity and set it to LocalSystem. Magcally, the whole thing worked.

Comment: This has disastrous consequences for server security!