# Why does my IIS7 application pool shutdown after an exception in a DLL called from an ASP.NET page?

Tags: exception, iis-7, application-pool

I've read the posts [ASP.NET application pool shutdown problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742122/asp-net-application-pool-shutdown-problem) and [IIS 7.5: problem with Application pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486482/iis-7-5-problem-with-application-pool) but they didn't answer my question.

I've got a C# ASP.NET page that in code-behind instantiates a class from a DLL supplied via the BIN directory, then calls a method on this instance. The method inside the DLL throws `System.ArgumentException` due to a non existing column in a `DataRow` object. The event log shows the following error:

```
Source: ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/...
Process ID: 9476
Exception: System.ArgumentException
Message: Column 'someColumn' does not belong to table.
StrackTrace:
```

The calling code in the ASP.NET page wraps the method call in a generic `try-catch` block. When I request the page, this crashes the corresponding application pool of my IIS instance and my web site is no longer available (Error 503). I manually have to restart the application pool and the site works again.

**Update**
As requested the `try catch` block from the ASP.NET code behind:

```
try
{
    SomeExternalClass someExternalClass = new SomeExternalClass();
    someExternalClass.SomeMethod( someId );
}
catch( Exception ex )
{
    // "smp" is an instance of "StatusMessagePanel", a control we use on all pages 
    // to show error information, basically a div container with an icon.
    smp.ShowError( ex.Message ); 
}
```

Now my question is why a relatively "simple" exception such as the `System.ArgumentException` being thrown when trying to access a non existing `DataRow` column, crashes the whole website? Neither does the generic `try-catch` block of the ASP.NET page help, nor should this be the reason to completely make the whole website unavailable, or is that a wrong assumption? I'd never have thought that this can basically take the (II)server down.

In anticipation of people telling me that I should check for column existence before I access them: I know about that and the legacy code has now been changed, but this isn't my question as described above, I'd like to know why the consequences are so drastic.

**Update 2**

The method in question being called inside the DLL starts a thread that is wrapped in a `try-catch` block:

```
[...]
try
{
    ThreadStart starter = () => CreateReport(...)
    Thread thread = new Thread( starter );
    thread.Start();
    if( !thread.Join( TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 15 ) ) )
    {
        // Log some timeout warning
    }
    else
    {
        // Log information about successful report generation
    }
}
catch( Exception ex )
{
    // Log error information
}
```

Comment: What happens in the catch block? If that throws an exception you could be in trouble. Can you post the try catch code?

Comment: The catch block calls a method that just makes the error message visible to the client (browser), I'll update my question.

Comment: Just to humour me - if you remove the try-catch block completely and just call the method, does the app pool still crash?

Comment: Will try when back at work :-)

Comment: Same as before. Removing the exception handling on the code behind of the ASP.NET page results in the application pool shutdown.

Comment: Does the external DLL use threads?

Comment: @leppie: Yes, it does start (in this case) a single thread, I'll update the question with some more details.

Comment: @Gorgsenegger: You need to somehow tag onto the `Thread.UnhandledException` event for that thread. It might be hard. It would be be better to place a try/catch in the body of the `ThreadStart` method. Edit: This means in the body of `starter`.

Comment: @leppie: So you mean a generic `try-catch` in the body of `starter` or explicitly catching `Thread.UnhandledException`?

Comment: @Gorgsenegger: Either would work, I prefer the former.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Most likely your application pool is being shut down automatically by [IIS's Rapid Fail Protection](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/failure) feature, as you note in the linked questions.  If you check your event log, there may be multiple unhandled exceptions being thrown in rapid succession.

Simply put, enough unhandled exceptions in a configurable timespan (the default is 5 in 5 minutes) will shut down the AppPool, causing the 503 Service Unavailable response.

The reasoning behind this feature is that if you have a faulty application, you probably don't want it to be automatically restarted on every subsequent request, consuming resources and possibly corrupting data.

I have to admit that this isn't the "default" behavior I would have expected either.

Check out [Rick Stahls explanation](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Dec/19/IIS-7-and-Rapid-Fail-Protection), it's a bit more in depth.

To really fix this, you need to catch the exception, or prevent the exception from being thrown (like @leppie suggests).  Unhandled exceptions are supposed to tear down the entire executing process (meaning that single request/worker process, not IIS) - it makes .Net code much easier to debug, because it doesn't hide the errors or simply hang the application.

Note that this was changed in .Net 2.0:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965.aspx
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911816

**Update**
Based on your update above, I don't think your exception is actually caught, if it is thrown from `CreateReport()`.  That method is executing on a separate thread:

[image: exception still thrown]

You need a try-catch in the body of `CreateReport()` if there isn't one already:

```
public static void CreateReport() {
    try {
        throw new Exception("reducto");
    } catch {
        Console.WriteLine("done did.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the more detailed information, although I still don't understand why an exception *that is being caught inside the DLL* can cause the application pool to shutdown. Multiple exceptions thrown in rapid succession should also not be the case as the execution of the DLL's method terminates with the first exception being thrown inside. The event log also shows that only one exception was generated.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to verify as soon as I find the time - we just moved our TFS to a different network and are still in the process of getting it up to speed again, so sorry for the delay and please bear with me for a couple of days.

Comment: That was it, indeed a little bit hidden. There was a `try catch` block in that method, but it only caught a single (different) kind of exception that didn't occur when I had the problems described in my question. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 4):

It happened to me once.  The real error(in my case) was a stack-overflow that was shutting down the pool.

It seem like IIS was protecting itself from consuming too much resources.

I found the problem using DebugDiag.

Here is where I started: http://www.webdebug.net/index.php/2012/12/collect-iis-crash-dump-with-debugdiag/

> I'd like to understand why an exception in an external DLL can cause the IIS application pool to shutdown, even if the exception is being caught inside the DLL and also when calling the DLL's method from within the code behind of the ASP.NET page.

The external dll also run in your application pool.  A major crash in this dll will also crash your application pool.  Some exceptions can't be handle and the stackoverflow exception is one of them.  Subject is discused [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599219/c-sharp-catch-a-stack-overflow-exception).  Maybe it is what happen in your case.