# Application overloading the pool

Tags: iis-7, application-pool, application-restart

There is a long time been trying to solve a pool next to my host (Shared host [locaweb.com.br](http://locaweb.com.br) )

### Always the error is displayed below:

[image: host]

### Logs

**Server erros log**

[The server error log](http://www.letsgofestas.com.br/erro.txt)

**App erros log**

[image: App Erros]

Answer (score 0):

In attached event log there's nothing about .net process which is failing, and we need that to identify the problem.

Try turning on debug="true" and trace="on" in web.config and accessing the site locally. It may display the actual .net error message.

There are similar problems mentioned here: 
[A process serving application pool 'Classic .NET AppPool' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. HTTP Error 503](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445566/a-process-serving-application-pool-classic-net-apppool-suffered-a-fatal-commu)

try follow their steps :)